# Algorithm to separate dark colors from light colors? (example: anything under #ffffff/2 is dark?)

Tags: javascript, colors

I have an iframe that needs to be embedded on various sites and 2 stylesheets (light and dark) are applied based on the site text color. At this moment, I apply the stylesheets this way:

- if text color > #ffffff / 2 => dark stylesheet
- if text color < #ffffff / 2 => light stylesheet

But obviously this doesn't always work.

So I need to find a better algorithm to separate dark colors from light colors. I know this can never be 100% accurate, but at least I need something that is better than my solution.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

---

*coffeescript code:*

```
calculateTheme = (hexcol)->
    if (parseInt(hexcol, 16) > 0xffffff/2)
      return "dark"
    else
      return "light"
```

Comment: Please read http://24ways.org/2010/calculating-color-contrast/ – maybe it will be helpful for you

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski funny how we both googled the same article ;)

Comment: Google for `HSV` - it's a great color format for what you're trying to do. While `RGB` simply says the proportion of red/blue/green (based on human vision's primary colours), HSV uses hue, saturation and brightness instead. Obviously, it's much easier to find out the relative brightness of two colours in HSV - just compare the brightness.

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought  that part of the problem lies in the fact that RGB colours have 3 elements and can be darkened or lightened, to make a mic of colours.

I.e: #FF0000 is red, but as the value decreases, it gets closer to dark red, #EE0000

The same principle applies to the other 2 components. I would recommend building the algorithm, where you extract all 3 components and then test, then to see how close they are to 00.

Source: http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm

EDIT: [This article](http://24ways.org/2010/calculating-color-contrast/) seems like a good source of information.

Answer (score 0):

Check if following code works

```
 function getNumberRange(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
 }

 function getRandomHexColor() {
  var result = "0x";
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      result += getNumberRange(0, 15).toString(16);
  }
  return result;
 }

var colorVal = getRandomHexColor();

if (colorVal > 0xffffff / 2) {
  alert(colorVal + " :  is light");
} else {
 alert(colorVal + " : is dark");
}
```